# Масштабирование графика с объектами

Tags: c++, opengl

Не могу понять как сделать масштабирование графика с объектами, чтобы он отдалялся и приближался. Я сделал регистрацию кнопок + и - для управление масштабирования(zoom++,zoom--.Что-то попробовал, но там просто чушь какая-то у меня получилось, просто ко всем параметрам прописал zoom + .
Вот код:

```
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <glut.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>


    # define M_PI           3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */

    LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

GLfloat FAngle, zoom = 0.0;

    void Axes(GLfloat cx, GLfloat cy, GLfloat cz, GLfloat size)
{
size = size / 2.0;
glBegin(GL_LINES);
// ось x
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(cx - size, 0.0, 0.0);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(cx + size, 0.0, 0.0);
// ось y
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, cy - size, 0.0);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, cy + size, 0.0);
// ось z
glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, cz - size);
glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, cz + size);
glEnd();
}

    void Cube(GLfloat cx, GLfloat cy, GLfloat cz, GLfloat size, byte rf, byte gf, byte bf, byte rt, byte gt, byte bt)
{
byte rm, gm, bm;
// вычислим промежуточный цвет
rm = rf + (rt - rf) / 2;
gm = gf + (gt - gf) / 2;
bm = bf + (bt - bf) / 2;
// рисуем грани куба
size = size / 2.0;
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// нижняя грань
glColor3ub(rf, gf, bf);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rt, gt, bt);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz - size);
// задняя грань
glColor3ub(rf, gf, bf);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rt, gt, bt);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz - size);
// левая грань
glColor3ub(rt, gt, bt);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rf, gf, bf);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz - size);
// передняя грань
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rf, gf, bf);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rt, gt, bt);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz + size);
// правая грань
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rt, gt, bt);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rf, gf, bf);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz + size);
// верхняя грань
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz - size);
glColor3ub(rf, gf, bf);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rm, gm, bm);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz + size);
glColor3ub(rt, gt, bt);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz - size);
glEnd();
}

    void Diag(GLfloat cx, GLfloat cy, GLfloat cz, GLfloat size)
{
size = size / 2.0;
glBegin(GL_LINES);
// первая пара диагоналей
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz - size);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz - size);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz - size);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz - size);
// вторая пара диагоналей    
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy - size, cz + size);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy + size, cz + size);
glVertex3f(cx - size, cy + size, cz + size);
glVertex3f(cx + size, cy - size, cz + size);
glEnd();
}

    int main()
{

//Получаем хендл приложения, потребуется при создании класса окна и самого окна.
HINSTANCE histance = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);

//Создаем класс окна.
WNDCLASSEX wclass = { 0 };          //Обнуляем структуру с самого начала, так как заполнять будем не все поля.
wclass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);      //По размеру структуры Windows определит, какая версия API была использована.
wclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;    //Говорим окну перерисовываться при изменении размеров окна.
wclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;        //Указываем функцию обработки сообщений.
wclass.hInstance = histance;        //Указываем хендл приложения.
wclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);    //GetStockObject возвращает хендл на белую кисточку, для фона окна
wclass.lpszClassName = "MYCLASS";      //Имя данного класса, должно быть уникальным, иначе, если класс с таким именем уже зарегестрирован, то в регистрации будет отказано.
//Регистрируем класс окна.
RegisterClassEx(&wclass);

HWND w;

//Создаем окно.
w = CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    L"MYCLASS",                //Имя класса.
    L"Title",                //Заголовок окна.
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, //WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,          //Тип окна, влияет на отображение системного меню, кнопок в верхнем правом углу и т.п.
    50, 50,                  //Координаты окна.
    500, 500,                //Ширина окна.
    0,                    //Ссылка на родительское окно.
    0,                    //Хендл меню.
    histance,                //Хендл приложения, получаем его функцией GetModuleHandleW.
    0
);

//Показываем окно, если этого не сделать окно не будет отображено.
ShowWindow(w, SW_SHOW);
//Обновляем окно.
UpdateWindow(w);

//Запускаем цикл обработки сообщений окна.
MSG msg = { 0 };
while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);  //Преобразуем виртуальную клавишу в ASCII-код и посылаем сообщение WM_CHAR (тут не нужно.Необходимо, если надо работать с текстом, вводимым с клавиатуры)
    DispatchMessage(&msg);  //Передаем сообщения для обработки в "главную функцию обработки сообщений"
}
return 0;
}
    LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg) {
case WM_DESTROY:// если этого не сделать, то все ваши жалкие попытки закрыть окно будут проигнорированы
    wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
    wglDeleteContext(wglGetCurrentContext());
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, wglGetCurrentDC());
    PostQuitMessage(0);// отправляет приложению сообщение WM_QUIT. Принимает код ошибки, который заносится в wParam сообщения WM_QUIT
    break;


case WM_CREATE:
    HGLRC RC;
    HDC   DC;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd, * ppfd;

    wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
    int pixelformat;
    ppfd = &pfd;
    ppfd->nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    ppfd->nVersion = 1;
    ppfd->dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    ppfd->dwLayerMask = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    ppfd->iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    ppfd->cColorBits = 16;
    ppfd->cDepthBits = 16;
    ppfd->cAccumBits = 0;
    ppfd->cStencilBits = 0;

    DC = GetDC(hWnd);       //1

    pixelformat = ChoosePixelFormat(DC, ppfd); //2
    SetPixelFormat(DC, pixelformat, ppfd);              //3
    RC = wglCreateContext(DC); //4
    wglMakeCurrent(DC, RC);     //5

    SetTimer(hWnd,    // дескриптор главного окна
        0,           // идентификатор таймера
        100,         // интервал - 0.10 секунды
        NULL);       // процедуры таймера нет
    break;

case WM_TIMER:
    FAngle = FAngle + 1.0;
    if (FAngle > 359.0) FAngle = 0.0;

    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
    break;

case WM_SIZE:

    WORD w, h;
    w = LOWORD(lParam);
    h = HIWORD(lParam);

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    break;
case WM_PAINT:

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch (wParam) {
    case 0xBB: {
        zoom++;
        break;
    }
    case 0xBD: {
        zoom--;
        break;
    }

    break;
    }
case WM_MOUSEHWHEEL:
    switch (wParam) {
    case MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP: {
        zoom++;
        break;
        }
    case MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN: {
        zoom--;
        break;
    }
    break;
    }

        // очищаем буфер кадра, устанавливая цвет его пикселей
        // равным цвету очистки
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        // будем рисовать полигоны линиями
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        // задаем видовое преобразование
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(-20.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(20.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        //рисуем оси координат
        Axes(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7);
        //рисуем зеленый куб c центром в начале координат и стороной 0.25
        // не применяя никакого преобразования моделирования
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(FAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, (zoom + 1.0));
        Cube(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 255, 0, 0, 128, 0); // clLime, clGreen
        Diag(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.25);
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(FAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        Cube(0.0, 0.0, -0.5, 0.25, 0, 255, 0, 0, 128, 0); // clLime, clGreen
        Diag(0.0, 0.0, -0.5, 0.25);
        glPopMatrix();
        //рисуем красный куб c центром точке (-0.5, 0.0, 0.0) и стороной 0.25
        //преобразование моделирования перенос и поворот относительно оси x
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(-FAngle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        Cube(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0); // clRed, clYellow
        //мы умеем рисовать диагонали только в плоскости, параллельной xOy
        //повернем его на 90 градусов относительно y,
           //чтобы он оказался в плоскости yOz
        glRotatef(-90.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        Diag(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25);
        glPopMatrix();
        //рисуем красный куб c центром точке (0.5, 0.0, 0.0) и стороной 0.25
           //преобразование моделирования – перенос и поворот относительно оси x
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(FAngle, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        Cube(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 255, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0); //clRed, clYellow
        glRotatef(90.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        Diag(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25);
        glPopMatrix();
        // рисуем синий куб c центром точке (0.0, -0.5, 0.0) и стороной 0.25
        // преобразование моделирования – перенос и поворот относительно оси y
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, -0.5, 0.0);
        glRotatef(-FAngle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        Cube(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255); // clAqua, clBlue
        glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        Diag(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25);
        glPopMatrix();
        // рисуем синий куб c центром точке (0.0, 0.5, 0.0) и стороной 0.25
           // преобразование моделирования – перенос и поворот относительно оси y
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.5, 0.0);
        glRotatef(FAngle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        Cube(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255); //clAqua, clBlue
        glRotatef(90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        Diag(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25);
        glPopMatrix();
        // после завершения рисования необходимо выполнить обмен буферов
        // для показа изображения пользователю
        SwapBuffers(wglGetCurrentDC());

        break;
}
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);//обрабатываем все остальные сообщения обработчиком "по умолчанию"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал `glScalef()` с помощью которого и получается масштабировать, если правильно указать команду в коде.

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        // задаем видовое преобразование

        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(-20.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        glRotatef(20.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        //рисуем оси координат
        glScalef(zoom,zoom, zoom);
        Axes(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.7);
```